# What is the name of the the live-CD installer?

Tags: installation, xubuntu

I am trying to install Xubuntu from a live-CD but when i click the icon on the desktop to install nothing happens.

How can I start that installer from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the installer is ubiquity. Try checking the md5 sum of the iso.

```
sudo ubiquity
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM